# Clementine refuses to play m4a, wma and wav

Tags: 13.10, clementine, m4a, wma, wav

I installed Clementine and I'm happy with it's user interface and certain features.

Unfortunately, it refuses to play wma, wav and m4a files.

As far as I know, I do have all the gstreamer plugins installed and the same files play well in Rythmbox, VLC and gnome-player.

I was getting gtreamer is missing a plugin error message. I installed gnome-codec-install and now it is giving me "internal data flow" error.

I searched the internet but to no avail. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Try installing ubuntu restricted extras from s/w center.

Comment: I installed the ubuntu-restricted-extras long before Clementine.

Comment: What release of Ubuntu are you using? Opps - i see 13.10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issues seem to go beyond codec install as clementine should play wav without anything.

In any event clementine uses gstreamer0.10 so make sure that these are installed:

- gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
- gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg

(don't think the gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly is needed but you could install it)

If there is still an issue then try deleting the `.bin` file inside `~/.gstreamer-0.10/`

Note that gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg is not available in 14.04 but can be had here: 
https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/gstffmpeg-keep

Comment: Deleting ~/.gstreamer-0.10/the .bin file inside solved the problem.

Comment: I also suggest to do restart after installing them.

Comment: In 15.10 I needed to install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg by the PPA.